# Erro instalando libapache2-mod-passenger no Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Estou sem conseguir instalar o libapache2-mod-passenger no Ubuntu. Tentei este comando:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

Porém retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
apache2_reload: Your configuration is broken. Not restarting Apache 2
```

O retorno completo é:

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  libapache2-mod-passenger
0 pacotes atualizados, 1 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 3 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 0 B/220 kB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 788 kB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado libapache2-mod-passenger.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 94884 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-passenger_4.0.37-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-passenger (4.0.37-2) ...
Configurando libapache2-mod-passenger (4.0.37-2) ...
apache2_invoke: Enable module passenger
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
apache2_reload: Your configuration is broken. Not restarting Apache 2
```

Comment: Rode o comando `apachectl configtest` e informe o output.

Comment: O comando que vc informou "apachectl configtest", não havia rodado,
então descobri que estava faltando o pacote "apache2-bin".
Depois de instalar este pacote, a instalação do "libapache2-mod-passenger" funcionou!
Vlw!!!  ^.^